# In Linux, if I have a bunch of text files is there a simple script to merge them into one file?

Tags: shell

For example suppose I have 1.csv, 2.csv, ... , 20.csv.  Is there a simple shell script where I can merge everything into merged.csv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use cat to concatenate them.

```
cat *.csv > merged.csv
```

As @sarnold points out this will concatenate them out of order. If that's important, use his for loop suggestion, or this xargs pipeline:

```
ls *.csv | sort -n | xargs cat > merged.csv
```

Comment: Finally a useful use of `cat`!

Comment: Note that this will probably misbehave for the specific case given by the user: `1.csv` will be followed by `10.csv`. Maybe it doesn't matter for @deltanovember, maybe it does.

Comment: One can always specify each filename individually if it does matter.

Comment: The order depends on how the shell expands `*.csv`. With Zsh, you can run `setopt NUMERIC_GLOB_SORT` and then `*.csv` will expand to `1.csv 2.csv ... 10.csv ... 20.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to merge files by appending the lines from one on to the end of the lines of the other, then you're looking for `paste`.

For example, if file1 contains:

```
1,One
2,Two
```

And file2 contains:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
```

You could run `paste -d , file1 file2` to get this:

```
1,One,A,B,C
2,Two,D,E,F
```

Comment: Excellent little utility, and a good reminder that many questions can have multiple interpretations. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer:

```
cat *.csv > merged.csv
```

will sort `1.csv 10.csv 2.csv 20.csv 3.csv...`. If you want them sorted by number, it takes a bit more work:

```
for i in `seq 1 20`; do cat ${i}.csv >> merged.csv ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat {1..20}.csv > merged.csv`

It's what cat was made for! Note that I've used a bash-ism in the `{1..20}` sequence.